# Loop over string characters in R

Tags: r, loops, for-loop

I'm trying to loop over a list of characters:

```
covariate_names <- c("Age_50.", "Age_30.49", "Age_18.29", "Income_High", "Income_Medium", "Income_Low",
                "DemographicSegment_Value.Seeker", "DemographicSegment_Established", "DemographicSegment_Planner", "DemographicSegment_Affluent",
                "DemographicSegment_Digital.Native","Gender_F..", "Gender_M..", "TransactionAmount",
                "TechTxns", "FashionTxns", "TravelTxns", "GamerTxns",
                "Recency", "Frequency", "Monetary", "Breadth", "Consistency", "is_donor", "donation_amt")
```

```
pairs <- function(df, covariate, group){
    pwc <- pairwise_t_test(data = df,
                           formula = as.formula(paste0(covariate,"~",group)),
                           paired = FALSE )
    pwc <- as.data.frame(pwc)
    pwc <- pwc %>% rename(GroupA = group1,
                     GroupB = group2,
                     N_grpA = n1, N_grpB = n2)
pwc <- pwc[,1:7]
pwc <- pwc %>%
    mutate_if(is.numeric, round, digits = 6)
    
    #print(pwc)
}
```

```
for (i in covariate_names){
    pwc_i <- pairs(df = df_test_TS, covariate = i, group = "w.contextual")
}
```

But the `pairs` function returns a df so I don't know if this is possible to use a loop for. I just want to run the pairs function for all of my covariates in the list, and be able to call to the output from each of the individual iteration of the `pairs` function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the function :

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

pairs <- function(df, covariate, group){
  pwc <- pairwise_t_test(data = df,
                         formula = reformulate(group, covariate),
                         paired = FALSE )
  pwc <- as.data.frame(pwc)
  pwc %>% 
    rename(GroupA = group1,
           GroupB = group2,
           N_grpA = n1, N_grpB = n2) %>%
    select(1:7) %>%
    mutate(across(where(is.numeric), round, digits = 6))
    #For older dplyr
    #mutate_if(is.numeric, round, digits = 6)
  
}
```

and then use `map`/`lapply` to get list as output :

```
result <- map(covariate_names, ~pairs(df_test_TS, .x, "w.contextual"))
```

If you want to combine the results into one dataframe use `map_df` :

```
result <- map_df(covariate_names, ~pairs(df_test_TS, .x, "w.contextual"))
```

Answer (score 0):

You would need to store your results in a list, using the loop. You can try next code:

```
#Data
covariate_names <- c("Age_50.", "Age_30.49", "Age_18.29", "Income_High", "Income_Medium", "Income_Low",
                     "DemographicSegment_Value.Seeker", "DemographicSegment_Established", "DemographicSegment_Planner", "DemographicSegment_Affluent",
                     "DemographicSegment_Digital.Native","Gender_F..", "Gender_M..", "TransactionAmount",
                     "TechTxns", "FashionTxns", "TravelTxns", "GamerTxns",
                     "Recency", "Frequency", "Monetary", "Breadth", "Consistency", "is_donor", "donation_amt")
#Function
pairs <- function(df, covariate, group){
  pwc <- pairwise_t_test(data = df,
                         formula = as.formula(paste0(covariate,"~",group)),
                         paired = FALSE )
  pwc <- as.data.frame(pwc)
  pwc <- pwc %>% rename(GroupA = group1,
                        GroupB = group2,
                        N_grpA = n1, N_grpB = n2)
  pwc <- pwc[,1:7]
  pwc <- pwc %>%
    mutate_if(is.numeric, round, digits = 6)
  
  #print(pwc)
}
```

Here the changes:

```
#List to store results
List <- list()
#Loop
for (i in 1:length(covariate_names)){
  List[[i]] <- pairs(df = df_test_TS, covariate = covariate_names[i], group = "w.contextual")
}
```